# Python twisted: 2 sequential, synchronous requests?

Tags: python, twisted, webclient

I'm using the Python twisted library to send client requests to a web server. I'm using twisted instead of requests, because the web server is a malware command&control server, and the request must follow very strict rules: e.g., the sequence of headers must be right. Requests does not give me the option to determine this. With twisted, this works. However, I don't really need the asynchronous overhead of twisted - but must follow it, so I can use it... My main problem now is that after 1 (synchronous) request was handled, I cannot  send a second one, because the reactor stopped and can't be restarted ... and a second reactor can't be created. But this is such a simple task that there must be a way? My current code basically looks like:

```
class WebClientContextFactory(ClientContextFactory):
  def getContext(self, hostname, port):
    return ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)

receivedData = None

def cbBody(body):
    global receivedData
    receivedData = body

def cbResponse(response):
    d = readBody(response)
    d.addCallback(cbBody)
    return d

class DataProducer(object):

    def __init__(self, body):
        self.body = body
        self.length = len(body)

    def startProducing(self, consumer):
        consumer.write(self.body)
        return defer.succeed(None)

    def pauseProducing(self):
        pass

    def stopProducing(self):
        pass

....

contextFactory = WebClientContextFactory()
agent = Agent(reactor, contextFactory)

....
d = agent.request('POST', url, Headers(headers), DataProducer(postData))
d.addCallbacks(cbResponse, err)
d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
reply = receivedData
```

The last 5 lines are repeated for a second requests later, but i then get an error that reactor is not restartable. This is probably a very stupid question, but how can that be solved?

Comment: Very simply explained, the "the asynchronous overhead" is required for twisted to work properly. Also the `requests` library is ver versatile and you might just solve the header problem by handing over an `OrderedDict` instead of a normal one.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, you're right about OrderedDict - I forgot about that, There are other reasons not to use reqeusst though, but I hesitate to discuss them in public (I don't want to tell malware authors how to detect researchers); the actual question though is, how to send 2 sequential twisted requests.

Comment: Anyway, I think I figured out how it would work, teh new reqeust must be created from within cbBody, and without callign stop.

Comment: Have you looked into `treq` it's a combination of twisted and requests